# How to run batch (.bat) file from Spring server

Tags: java, spring

I would like to run a bat file from my Spring server. I already have a method in my client, but I want to run the bat on my server.

How can I do this?

Edit:
My intention was to upload a batch file from my Client to my Server, and then the Server should run it and show me in command Line what is happening.

Edit.2: 
this would be the part of my Server where i upload? I think im missing something how do i tell my batchfile.Batchfile which file is the (.bat)

```js
@PostMapping("/file/upload")
    public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest req,
                                 @RequestParam("uid") String uid,
                                 @RequestParam("size")long size,
                                 @RequestParam("fname") String fname,
                                 @RequestParam("projectname")String projectname) throws IOException {
        QueueEntry queueEntry = new QueueEntry(uid, new Date(), QueueEntry.Status.EXECUTING, size, fname, projectname);
        deque.add(queueEntry);

        storageService.store(file, req.getHeader("author"));
        batchFile.BatchFile();

        queueEntry.setStatus(QueueEntry.Status.FINISHED);
    }
```

I hope i could explain it well enough.

Client `BatchFile` class used for execution:

```
public class BatchFile {

    public void BatchFile(File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException 

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
        processBuilder.directory(file.getParentFile());
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println(process.waitFor());
    }
```

Comment: What is a spring server?

Comment: im not good at explaining maybe this will help https://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series

Comment: Break your problem into 2 parts: 1. Uploading file to the server. 2. Execute the file. Seems like point#2 is already sorted. You need to work on just #1 for now.

Comment: i Edit a part of my Server Code

Comment: Take care to properly secure this service, because that **opens a door for [Code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)**